# Can I specify which cultures to use when generating local resource files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, localization

I am working on a website that is English by default and optionally in Spanish. I am generating local resource files for each page with language appropriate content for various items.

So far to create my pair of resource files (default and Spanish) for each page, visual studio 2010 generates the first file like `default.aspx.resx`. I create the Spanish version manually by copying the default file and renaming to `default.aspx.es.resx`.

Is there a way to have visual studio generate both files for me? I can generate the default file, add controls to the page, and generate again and visual studio is smart to not blow away any work I've done in that file. I would like to be able to also update the Spanish resource file automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool in Visual Studio (at least I haven't found one when researching the same request), and we dropped the idea of writing smart macros for that purpose that parse resx files and modify other based on changes.

There is, however, a decent free tool that supports creating and aligning resources: [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com).

You can add files and entries on click, and editing resources is much nicer than in Visual Studio, in addition to quite a few other useful features.

Comment: I tried out zeta and it was good enough for what I needed. You can open a set of resource files and do a side by side editing. zeta will will add the appropriate key automatically if it is missing from some version of the resource.